# How to optimize df.assign?

Tags: python, pandas, assign

I'm working on python on a dataframe(`data`) of shape (55025, 12) and I'm trying to assign a new column, my code is:

```
data_cat=data.assign(
    type0 = lambda dataframe: dataframe['value'].map(lambda x: x>0),
    type1= lambda dataframe: dataframe['value'].map(lambda x: x>1,
    type2 = lambda dataframe: dataframe['value'].map(lambda x: x>2)
)
```

and it's taking forever to run. How can I optimize this?

Thanks!

Comment: `dataframe['value'].map(lambda x: x>0)` can be written as  `dataframe['value'].gt(0)` this might optimize it a bit. `lt`-> less than, `gt`-> greater than, `le`-> less than equal to, similarly `ge`, `eq`

Comment: `lambda dataframe: dataframe['value'].map(lambda x: x>0)` can be written as `type0 = data['value'].gt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create new columns on the original dataframe directly to avoid copying data, if it won't hurt.

```
data["type0"] = data["value"].gt(0)
data["type1"] = data["value"].gt(1)
...
```

otherwise `assign` is fine

```
data_cat = data.assign(
    type0=data["value"].gt(0),
    type1=data["value"].gt(1),
    ...
)
```

See also [pandas accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html) for some other frequent operations that may have been already implemented in pandas.